# How to use explode function for arrays in scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, function, apache-spark

I have the following data frame:

| _name | data |
| --- | --- |
| Test | {[{0, 0, 1, 0 }]} |

I want the output as:

| allNames | data |
| --- | --- |
| Test | 0 |
| Test | 0 |
| Test | 1 |
| Test | 1 |

I tried the explode function, but the following code just returns the same data frame as above with just the headers changed. How can I change the code to get the expected output?

```
  val t = cabinetDF.select(col("_attrname").as("allNames"),functions.explode(array(col("ROWDATA"))))
  t.show(false)
```

Comment: what is `{[{0, 0, 1, 0 }]}`? This does not look like a valid Spark data type.

Comment: I used struct type to read the data from XML and this is what I am getting. Do I need to convert it into an array first?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, but then I'm creating an ordinary array.  I'm not sure why yours is wrapped in an additional set of curly brackets and an additional set of square brackets:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.sqlContext.implicits._

val df = Seq( ("Test", Array( 0, 0, 1, 0 ) ) )
  .toDF("_name", "data")

df.show

val df2 = df
  .withColumn("x", explode($"data"))
  .select("_name", "x")
  
df2.show
```

My results:

[image: Results]

Perhaps you need to unpack it first or look at how it's being created in the first place.

Comment: I read the data from an XML using struct type and this the format I am getting, any idea how I can get rid of those?